# Byte order in memory after storing a 16-bit number on 8086?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, x86-16, endianness

I'm studying 8086 assembly language at high school and I have this question:

For example I have this number ABCD (hex). How is it stored on the memory?

Does the AB go for example to memory address 01 and the CD goes to address 02?

Comment: you should press the "accept" on answers more often.

Answer (score 10):

8086 stores the values in [little endian format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess#Little-endian). So the lower order byte (i.e. CD) is stored first and then the higher order byte is stored. So in your case it will be address 01 will have CD and 02 will have AB.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system you're working on.

x86 systems use little endian, so the value ABCD would appear in memory as CD followed by AB

Answer (score 1):

8086 uses little [endian format](http://v86-64.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: No Idea what it means sorry :\ I'm still an high-school student and our computer knowledge level is pretty low in compare to university.

Comment: CD - AB. You should read the Wikipedia article about endianness : )